# Bot Framework - Email Channel To send Email Via Directline C# Bot

Tags: c#, email, botframework, bots, email-attachments

I want to use email channel of bot framework to send email via bot if bot is unable to provide help required.

I have configured an outlook office 365 email and successfully added to the email channel of my bot.

As I have never used the email channel before I am not sure of the channel data that has to be set in case of email, I have no idea what is missing or if there's some error in reply creation.

I want to send direct email from bot to user's email id with some relevant details, user to whom email will be sent is not involved in conversation.

I am getting bad request error while trying to send the email via following code:

```
ChannelAccount botAccount = new ChannelAccount(  
  id: $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BotEmail"]}".ToLower(),
  name: $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BotId"]}")
  { Id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BotEmail"]};  
ChannelAccount userAccount = new ChannelAccount(  
  id: $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserEmail"]}", 
  name: "Vanjuli")
  { Id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserEmail"]}; 

  var serviceURL = @"https://email.botframework.com/";  
  MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceURL, DateTime.MaxValue);
 using (var _connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceURL)))  
 {   
  ConversationResourceResponse conversationId = await _connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);
  IMessageActivity reply = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
  reply.From = botAccount;  
  reply.Recipient = userAccount;
  ConversationAccount conversationAccount = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId.Id);
  reply.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId.Id);
  reply.Text = "This is dummy text of an email!";
  reply.Locale = "en-Us";   
  await _connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)reply);
}
```

I would also like to send attachments via email and send email to a group (service desk or group of email ids), is it possible to do so via email channel from a bot deployed on website or are there any challenges or risks ?

According to Microsoft documentation bot receives all emails from the registered mail and can reply to any email but what I am trying to achieve is sending email explicitly which is not a reply to any previous mail. Is something like this possible for a bot which is not solely an email chatbot or is deployed on a website?

Comment: Just to be sure: your bot is deployed on other channels than email, and your goal is, in some cases, to send an email when the bot cannot answer (on those channels), right?

Comment: Yes, directline bot is using webchat channel and is rendered on SharePoint website as help assistant. It guides user for the queries and for the query for which it couldn't find answer it must send email to some support group with relevant issue description or attachments provided by user.

Comment: Ok, if the workflow is only like you said, I would highly suggest to avoid mapping Email channel and simply send your email with whatever sender you prefer (SmtpClient, SendGrid...). Using email channel is overkill

Comment: Yes, I can understand your point of view but I would like to try the same using email channel to showcase how bot can use multiple channels. I want to know what mistake I am doing while sending reply. My client is keen on using email channel and wants us to explore that first , hence it's important for me to use the email channel if possible.

Comment: If you want to showcase the use of multiple channels, do your normal workflow with several channels. Not a single send, that's not the intent of multi channel. If you want more help with your error, add more details about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the intent is admirable, the approach **is not** recommended at all, and was not intended to mix the channels in such a manner.

Nicholas is correct; if you want to showcase multiple channels, it's best to not have them in a single